# Geometry Nodes, creating a ruffle effect - changing mesh along a curve profile?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am trying to recreate this ruffle (see ref image), I have a bezier curve profile that is thicker on the outside and would like to add noise or waves for movement, however only on the thicker bit and not on the lower part of the curve profile if that makes sense.

Any ideas here?

Cheers

[image: reference]
[image: geonodes]

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this task as follows:

[image]

Here I use a Bezier curve as a profile curve. In this case, its center is at $(0,0,0)$. By resampling the curve, and capturing how far the positions of the points extend into the range $-y$, I can use this value as a scale for the noise.

It depends on how your profile curve is positioned, but if its center is at $(0,0,0)$, then it should work fine for you. In fact you have several possibilities here. The only important thing is that you store the values for a scaling, which you get from the positions of the points, in the point domain of the profile curve beforehand. This way these values remain after using `Curve to Mesh` and can be used for a scaling afterwards.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>